# Angular / Typescript Radio Button two models

Tags: angular, typescript, data-binding

I dont quite know how to word my issue, perhaps that's why I can't find a solution.

I have an ngfor but then then need to bind another list of data to show the checked options:

I have a list of heroes:

```
[
    {id: 1, name:'Superman'},
    {id: 2, name:'Batman'},
    {id: 5, name:'BatGirl'},
    {id: 3, name:'Robin'},
    {id: 4, name:'Flash'}
];
```

I then show a select list as follows:

```
<div class="form-check" *ngFor="let p of heroes">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="{{p.id}}" id="{{p.id}}">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="{{p.id}}">
    {{p.name}}
  </label>
</div>
```

I then have the person with their favorite super heroes as another list:

```
{id: 1, name: 'Jack', favoiriteSuperHeoros: [ {id: "1"} , {id: "2"} ]}
```

How do I get the data to bind to the checkboxes?

Here is where I am working on it: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-muaxwi?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: The list of heroes is displayed on something like a user profile (e.g. Jack) and you want to set the checkbox of those heroes (two-way?) that the user has marked as favorite, is that correct?

Comment: that stackblitz is just default stacblitz.

Comment: @GunnarB. thats correct. I have updated the stackblitz link, please let me know if its working.

Comment: @AT82 i have updated the link and saved the stackblitz :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this works https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-acbft3?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

It's not quite optimal though (using a function to check the checked state of the checkbox while using default change detection). I also changed the fav-heroes prop on the person to plain number array (object array with string props is a mismatch for number ids).

Another option would be to create a mapped hero list (add a checked property) and bind that. This way you'd just toggle a boolean on that object.
This could be set once on initialization and then only on change. That reduces the number of recalculations.